# Drupal nodes displayed recursively by taxonomy hierarchy

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I've got a set of nodes categorized by audience and then further categorized by content type (all in the same vocabulary and storing the full taxonomy hierarchy).

I'd like to display these on a single page as follows.

```
AUDIENCE (PARENT TERM)

Category1 (Child Term)
- node1 (title,teaser,whatever)

Category2 (Child Term)
- node2
- node3

Category3 (Child Term)
- Sub-Category1 (Child1 of Category3)
-- node4
-- node5
- Sub-Category2 (Child2 of Category3)
-- node4
-- node5
etc.
```

It seems like there should be a module for this, but I've tried a few.  Taxonomy Lineage seems to get closest, but I haven't gotten it to work.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Views probably (Most certainly) can do this somehow, but it may require some theming/templating to get it lined up as you wish.

I'm sure you can make a linked list of node titles split by taxonomy term. If not in views 1 or 2, 3 should enable it.

Comment: Thanks JV.  I finally found the "Lineage Nested Link" style in Taxonomy Lineage module.    Using Hierarchy as the Nesting Field did the trick.  Can't believe how much time I spent on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

@j-oh-n - thank you very much! I've been investigating similar problem and finally I've found the answer!

Let me just explain how to find such option.

Style settings ->
Style: Lineage nested list ->
Nesting Field:
Taxonomy: Hierarchy

Just don't foget to add Taxonomy: Hierarchy as a field!